# Nginx is not able to handle a large number of requests

Tags: nginx, artifactory, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an scenario on where a nginx is in front of an Artifactory server.
Recently, while trying to pull a big number of docker images in a for loop, all at the same time (first test was with 200 images, second test with 120 images), access to Artifactory gets blocked, as nginx is busy processing all the requests and users will not be able to reach it.

My nginx server is running with 4 cpu cores and 8192 of ram.

I have tried to improve the handling of files in the server, by adding the bellow:

```
sendfile on;
sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
tcp_nopush on;
```

This made it a bit better (but of course, pull's of images with 1gb+ take much more time, due to the chunk size) - still, access to the UI would cause a lot of timeouts.

Is there something else that i can do to improve the nginx performance, whenever a bigger load is pushed thru it?

I think that my last option is to increase the size of the machine (more cpu's) aswell as the number of processes on nginx (8 to 16).

The full nginx.conf file follows bellow:

```
user              www-data;
worker_processes 8;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  19000;
}

http {
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    sendfile on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
    tcp_nopush on;

    set_real_ip_from 138.190.190.168;
        real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;

        log_format custome '$remote_addr - $realip_remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_time'
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';


    server {
            listen 80 default;
            listen [::]:80 default;
            server_name _;
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    ###########################################################
    ## this configuration was generated by JFrog Artifactory ##
    ###########################################################

    ## add ssl entries when https has been set in config
    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/{{ hostname }}.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/{{ hostname }}.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ## server configuration
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name ~(?<repo>.+)\.{{ hostname }} {{ hostname }} _;

        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
            set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
        }
        ## Application specific logs
        access_log /var/log/nginx/{{ hostname }}-access.log custome;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/{{ hostname }}-error.log warn;
        rewrite ^/$ /webapp/ redirect;
        rewrite ^//?(/webapp)?$ /webapp/ redirect;
        rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/$repo/$1/$2;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        location / {
            proxy_read_timeout  900;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size  10240m;
            proxy_pass_header   Server;
            proxy_cookie_path   ~*^/.* /;
            proxy_pass          http://{{ appserver }}:8081/artifactory/;
            proxy_set_header    X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
            proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the tips.

Cheers,
Ricardo

Comment: How do you know that Nginx and not Artifactory is the limiting process?

Comment: I have monitoring in place and can isolate the peak - and it's on nginx, not on Artifactory. Nevertheless, im triggering a new test directly on artifactory (bypassing nging) to exclude that scenario.

Comment: Seems it's not possible to test directly against Artifactory, for docker images.. But i re-checked again grafana, and Artifactory was at 25% CPU usage, while nginx was peaking at max available cpu. Also, disk utilization was very high on nginx (but probably because of image size, as there was not enough memory and it was going to disk).

Comment: Can you test Nginx without TLS enabled?